# Cardinality of cantor set $K$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cardinals

Is the Cantor function bijective from $[0,1]$ to Cantor set $K$? As $K$ is uncountable I think cardinality of $K$ must be $\mathfrak c$ as $K$ is a subset of $[0,1]$. But I am surprised whether there is any connection between cardinality and measure of a set. But in particular I am asking cardinality of $K$ and if it is $\mathfrak c$ give me a bijection with $K$ and $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) that I know is not a bijection.  If $\frac 13 \lt x \lt \frac 23, f(x)=\frac 12$  It is true that the cardinality of $K$ is $\mathfrak c$.  In the reals, all sets that have positive measure have cardinality $\mathfrak c$, but there are sets ($K$ among them) that have cardinality $\mathfrak c$ and measure $0$

Comment: ok, Cantor function is not bijective. But give me some proof that card K = c

Comment: Give a proof that card(K)=c

Comment: Have you seen that $K$ consists of all base $3$ expansions that have only $0$'s and $2$'s?  That is uncountable by the usual Cantor diagonal argument.  You can also change the $2$'s to $1$s and read them as binary to get an (up to  a countable set) bijection to $(0,1)$

Comment: The Cantor function is not bijective, but it does map $K$ onto $[0,1]$, showing the cardinal of $K$ is at least the cardinal of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I wanted to know abt the following map f:[0,1]to K. let x=0.x_1 x_2 x_3...be the binary rep of x in [0,1] then f(x)= 0.(2x_1)(2x_2)(2x_3).....then f(x) is in K. If we consider a unique binary rep of x earlier I think f is 1-1. Is the map f bijection  between [0,1] and k?

Comment: Almost but not quite.  For $x=0.100000\dots, f(x)=0.200000\dots$, so what maps to $0.02222222 \dots?$  It is only a countable set of instances, so can be patched up, but it takes a bit of patching.

Comment: .01111111....... maps 0.0222222....

Comment: What will be the problem for f to be surjective??

Comment: Then what maps to $0.2?$ in binary $0.1=0.011111\dots $ You can use either, but not both. One violates surjectivity.

Comment: @EuReka It is easy to modify Cantor's function to give us an injection of $[0,1]$ into $K$: If $f(x)=a$ has more than one solution, $a$ lies in an interval $[\alpha,\beta]$ where $\alpha,\beta\in K$ and $(\alpha,\beta)$ is one of the removed bits. Let $g(a)=\alpha$.